# function simplify argument list

Tags: php

When calling a function is there a way to simplify the argument list? Instead of using `$blank`.

```
$subscribe=1;
    $database->information($blank,$blank,$blank,$blank,$blank,$blank,$subscribe,$blank,$blank,$blank,$blank,$blank);



    function information ($search,$id,$blank,$category,$recent,$comment,$subscribe,$pages,$pending,$profile,$deleted,$reported) {
    //code
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in an array with the specified keys, and merge it with an array of default values

So instead of

```
function foo($arg1 = 3, $arg2 = 5, $arg3 = 7) { }
```

You'd have

```
function foo($args) {
   $defaults = array(
      'arg1' => '',
      'arg2' => null,
      'arg3' => 7
   );

   // merge passed in array with defaults
   $args = array_merge($defaults, $args);

   // set variables within local scope
   foreach($args as $key => $arg) { 
       // this is to make sure that only intended arguments are passed
       if(isset($defaults[$key])) ${$key} = $arg; 
   }

    // rest of your code
}
```

Then call it as

```
foo(array('arg3' => 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pass an array instead, or refactor. A long arguments list is usually a bad smell.

```
function information(array $params) {....

information(array('search'=>'.....
```

Comment: I was writing the same reply, +1 for the array approach. It gives you way more freedom and usability, expecially if you use reflections or dynamic calls.

Comment: I don't think you can use type hinting with arrays, only Objects.

Answer (score 2):

Twelve arguments are generally too many for one function. It's likely that your code could be simplified (including the argument lists getting shorter) by refactoring `function information` which looks likely to be a monster.

Stopgap measures you can use in the meantime are

- adding default argument values
- making the function accept all its arguments as an array

Both of the above will require you to visit *all* call sites for the function for review and modification.

Adding default arguments is IMHO the poor choice here, as by looking at the example call it seems that you would need to make *all* arguments default, which in turn means that the compiler will never warn you if you call the function wrongly by mistake.

Converting to an array is more work, but it forces you to rewrite the calls in a way that's not as amenable to accidental errors. The function signature would change to

```
function information(array $params)
```

or possibly

```
function information(array $params = array())
```

if you want *all* parameters to be optional. You can supply defaults for the parameters with

```
function information(array $params) {
    $defaults = array('foo' => 'bar', /* ... */);
    $params += $defaults; // adds missing values that have defaults to $params;
                          // does not overwrite existing values
```

To avoid having to rewrite the function body, you can then use `export` to pull out these values from the array into the local scope:

```
    export($params); // creates local vars
    echo $foo; // will print "bar" unless you have given another value
```

**[See all of this in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/m4tP9c)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it so the function wil automatically fill the variable with a given value like an empty string:

```
function information ($subscribe, $search="", $id="", $blank="", $category="", $recent="", $comment="", $pages="", $pending="", $profile="", $deleted="", $reported="") {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways:

- Accept an associative array as a single argument, and pass what you need to that. Throw exceptions if a critical argument is missing.
- Place critical arguments at the head of the function definition, and optional ones at the end. Give them a default value so that you don't have to declare them.
- Recosinder your function. 12 arguments is much too many for one function. Consider using a class/object, or dividing the work between different functions.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways:

```
function test($input = "some default value") {
    return $input; // returns "some default value"
}

function test($input) {
    return $input;
}

test(NULL); // returns NULL

function test() {
   foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
       echo $arg;
   }
}

test("one", "two", "three"); // echos: onetwothree
```